# Adding x seconds worth of time onto a string variable time of HH:MM

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, strptime, python-datetime

I'm trying to work out a way to make a new variable `AUTOMATIC_END_TIME` based on adding the minimum amount of time onto the start time but I can't figure out the way to allow `START_TIME` to be turned into a time that can then have time added onto it.

So far my script has the following:

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

START_TIME = "19:18"
END_TIME = "19:25"

LOGA = ["one", "two"]

TIME_DIFFERENCE = datetime.strptime(END_TIME, "%H:%M") - datetime.strptime(START_TIME, "%H:%M")
TIME_DIFFERENCE = TIME_DIFFERENCE.seconds

if len(LOGA) * (60 * (5 + 1)) >= TIME_DIFFERENCE:
    print "Show minimum end time"
    AUTOMATIC_END_TIME = "" # Should come out as 19:30
```

The current script shouldn't change at all except for `AUTOMATIC_END_TIME` which should be `START_TIME + (60 * (5 + 1)` It should come out as `19:30`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> (datetime.strptime(START_TIME, "%H:%M") + timedelta(minutes=12)).strftime('%H:%M')
'19:30'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

START_TIME = "19:18"
END_TIME = "19:25"

LOGA = ["one", "two"]

TIME_DIFFERENCE = datetime.strptime(END_TIME, "%H:%M") - datetime.strptime(START_TIME, "%H:%M")
TIME_DIFFERENCE = TIME_DIFFERENCE.seconds

if len(LOGA) * (60 * (5 + 1)) >= TIME_DIFFERENCE:
    print "Show minimum end time"
    AUTOMATIC_END_TIME = (datetime.strptime(START_TIME, "%H:%M") + timedelta(minutes=12)).strftime('%H:%M')
    print AUTOMATIC_END_TIME
```